# Websites (PHP and Django) routing with NGinx

Tags: django, apache, nginx

I have my first website running properly under Apache Web Server which shows homepage and it can be accessed at http://localhost:8989/.

I also have my second website which is a Django application (run under uWsgi) running properly at http://localhost:8000/ and each page is shown properly.

Now, I wanted to use Nginx to serve all static resources of both websites. Since I want to use my **the only one domain** for both website, so called www.test.com (TEST), I configure it as follows:

```
   server {
        listen 80;        
        server_name _;

        location / {
                root /var/www/statics;
                index index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri @home;
        }

        #for request: https://www.test.com/ , it should go to the 1st website
        location @home {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8989;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

        #for request: https://www.test.com/abc , it should go to the 2st website
        location /abc {
                rewrite ^/abc(.*) $1 break;

                try_files $uri @abc;
        }

        location @abc {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
   }
```

Not sure whether there is a better configuration, my requirement is as follows:

- having a website running on TEST
- If I go to TEST/ --> it should show my 1st website (PHP app)
- If I go to TEST/abc --> it should show my 2nd website (Django app) and all the links without problems and possibly without the need to change its settings.py or urls.py files
- I would like to manage all rerouting from the NGinx server

The current state with the above configuration:

- If I go to TEST/, it is routed to my 1st website (which is correct)
- If I go to TEST/abc, it is routed to my 2nd website (which is correct). However, whenever I click on hyperlinks inside it, such as to see a page on http://localhost:8000/login (which is run properly), with this re-route configuration, it is now become http://www.test.com/login, which in this case displaying Error 404: Not Found, and it seems request does not go to the second website but the first one instead (which is wrong). The expected request should be http://www.test.com/abc/login (all request inside the 2nd website should somehow now accessible through uri starting with "abc/" )

Anyone having experience like this? what is the correct Regex or Rewrite should be done in the Nginx configuration? or should it be done on the Django configuration instead? I prefer not to change each app's urls.py of the Django project, but if there is actually a simple trick need to do on its settings.py file, it would be great. Please help